# Does SARS-COV-2 produce toxins?

Tags: microbiology, virology

I wonder whether toxins are produced only by bacteria and fungi and not by viruses. Looking at the paper below, I read that several toxic proteins are produced by SARS-COV-2. Can these proteins be considered toxins?

Reference:
Lee, JG., Huang, W., Lee, H. et al. Characterization of SARS-CoV-2 proteins reveals Orf6 pathogenicity, subcellular localization, host interactions and attenuation by Selinexor. Cell Biosci 11, 58 (2021). https://doi.org/10.1186/s13578-021-00568-7

Comment: Please define what **you** understand by the word “toxin”. (And if you do that you will presumably be able to answer the question yourself.) As far as I am aware, the words has no unique scientific meaning, outside, perhaps, the specialism of bacteriology. It is enough that viruses infect and often destroy cells without getting into semantic arguments about toxicity.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the key here is the definition of "toxin" in a biology context. The best definition I have found is [this one](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/toxin) from Merriam-Webster:

> Definition of toxin
>
> : a poisonous substance that is a specific product of the metabolic
> activities of a living organism and is usually very unstable, notably
> toxic when introduced into the tissues, and typically capable of
> inducing antibody formation.

Key aspects of this definition include that it is "a specific product of the metabolic activities of a living organism " (so e.g. cyanide or even HCl would not be considered toxins) and that it is "notably toxic". It's the latter characteristic that the SARS-CoV-2 proteins fail, as your article link shows at most roughly 50% cell mortality when the various ORFs are overexpressed in target cells.

Basically, those proteins are nowhere near toxic enough to be considered "toxins".

A [WHO publication on biosafety](https://www.who.int/csr/resources/publications/biosafety/WHO_CDS_EPR_2006_6.pdf) (Lab biosecurity guidelines, Sept, 2006 WHO/CDS/EPR/2006.6) includes the description:

> Toxins  are  poisonous  substances  produced  by  living cells or
> organisms.

Comment: And you go to an English dictionary to find the meaning of a supposedly scientific word?

Comment: As I said, it's the best definition I could find. I think the "specific product of a living organism" and "notably toxic" aspects are key. I did not check dictionaries in other languages, but as you imply, those may provide additional useful information :)

Comment: I am not interested in dictionaries in any language unless I wish to find the first recorded usage of a term. For scientific meaning I would either consult a document on standards or nomenclature in the area or research usage in scientific publications.

Comment: Thanks. I was going on my own usage as a practitioner and finding a pre-existing definition that matched that.